# ABRecordCopyCompositeName android alternative

Tags: android

Is there an android alternative that functions like ABRecordCopyCompositeName on iOS which takes first name and last name then return a display name according to the language and locale of the name?

Answer (score 1):

Just find a way to do this:
In android contact app source code : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/ContactsCommon/+/android-5.0.2_r1

There's an `NameConverter.java` file in utils. It can separate name from display name or vice versa.

The con of this method is it requires `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS` or `android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS` permission.

I suppose there's a better solution than this.

Edit: 
Find another way:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/ContactsProvider/

There's a `NameSplitter.java`, which is how android system do this and does not request any permission.

Here's how you can use this:

```
NameSplitter nameSplitter = new NameSplitter(
        "",//getString(com.android.internal.R.string.common_name_prefixes),
        "",//getString(com.android.internal.R.string.common_last_name_prefixes),
        "",//getString(com.android.internal.R.string.common_name_suffixes),
        "",//getString(com.android.internal.R.string.common_name_conjunctions),
        Locale.getDefault());
NameSplitter.Name name = new NameSplitter.Name();
name.fullNameStyle = ContactsContract.FullNameStyle.UNDEFINED;
name.familyName = getLastName();
name.givenNames = getFirstName();
nameSplitter.guessNameStyle(name);
String displayName = nameSplitter.join(name, true, true);
```